# requestPermissions() for gps inside a service . Error:"location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission."

Tags: android, service, permissions, android-gps

The Problem I am facing is giving gps permissions to the application through service I am writing. 
I tried finding an example to achieve this and examples shows writing a gpslocation finder in Activity, but in this case, i would like to implement this in service.

The Service code is as follows:

```
public class TravelService extends Service{

    private LocationManager locManager;
    private LocationListener locListener;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 100, locListener);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 100, locListener);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 100, locListener);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service destroyed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is my code in the Manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.param.dateandtime">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--  Entry for LoginActivity.class -->
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Finish"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <service android:name=".TravelService"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here I have attached the error log, showing the error I'm facing. I can see the error as "location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission."
[Error log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFQ2E.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: I posted my manifest.xml code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request permissions from service since a service is not tied to a UI.
So do it from the activity when you `startService()`.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number can be used
```

And implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1001: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    //Start your service here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am checking for permissions onCreate() it self right. So, through out the service is running it should have permissions. But what I want is how to give permissions in the onCreate() method in a service.

Comment: I thought you know how to do that but you commented out that code and posted it. Updated the answer.

Comment: When I use ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() in the service it is expecting the first argument as an activity and showing error like this: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-iV4t1YB_hZU/Vxpow_fqGxI/AAAAAAAAEQU/3Wzup0D-02o7ys00VopOYg4ov9v1SfsOwCL0B/w739-h229-no/error1.png

Comment: Oops, missed that , Updated the answer.

Comment: Still not working. Because "this" is referring the LocationListener here. Can you share if you have any service written using GPS.

Comment: You can change that to "YourActivity.this"